# Azure DevOpsが無料で使用できる人数について

Tags: azure

Azure DevOpsでは無料で5人まで使用可能で、無料枠を超えた場合は超えた人数分の料金が請求されますが、この5人というのはどの単位を表しているのでしょうか?

より詳細な質問としましては、以下の選択肢の内Azure DevOpsの料金体系はどれに当てはまるでしょうか?

- 1プロジェクトあたり5人まで無料
- 1organization(Azure DevOpsで作成/削除するもの)あたり5人まで無料
- 組織(会社などの実際のもの)に所属する人数分のライセンスをまとめて購入しようとしたときに5人まで無料
- 上記3例以外

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この無料の範囲は購入者やAzure ADベースで動いているのか、MSアカウントで動いているのかでいろいろ変わります。

- MSアカウントで動いている場合

  - organization単位で5人ずつのはずです
- Azure ADで動いている場合

  - [Multi Organization Billing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/pay-for-users-once-across-organizations/)を有効にしていると、サブスクリプション単位で5人です。
  - これが無効の場合はOrganization 単位で5人のはずです。
- Visual Studio サブスクリプションを持っている人はこの無料枠に入りません。その場合、Visual Studioサブスクリプションに関連付けられているAzure ADかMSアカウントでログインしなくてはなりません。

Comment: Multi Organization Billingが無効で、あるMSアカウントのユーザが無料枠を超過したOrganizationに複数加入している場合はそれぞれのOrganizationで請求が発生するということでしょうか?

Comment: Org A、Org Bに無料枠の5人がいて、どちらにも6人目として同じ foo というMSアカウントが入ると、どちらにも課金が発生するはずです。